# Can't send email with server.sendmail()

Tags: python

I am trying to send an email using python but it wont send anything. Any fixes?

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()

try:
 with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
   server.login(sender_email, password)
   server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message1)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
finally:
  server.quit()
```

Comment: Can we have your error trace ?

Comment: the error literally tells you to run the `.connect()` method before you call which ever line is throwing the error, have you tried that?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen didnt work

Comment: then please give full error message (we need to know which line is failing) and assuming adding `.connect()` gave a different error show that as well.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen done

Comment: ok wait, I just noticed you have 2 variables called `server`, one created before the `with` statement and one made within the `with` statement, and I would suspect the with statement is already taking care of quitting the connection.  Do you need the 2 connections? I'm wondering if you want to just remove all the code in the `try/except` the is outside the `with` statement.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that did it, no more error but it's not sending any mails either :/
it just gives me this: python -u "c:\Users\Lundqvist\Desktop\food\weekstuff.py"

Comment: you say no error, but is there an error that you are catching and printing out? that is still very much an error, I don't see any reason why `sendmail` would just not do anything and not throw an error.

Comment: not printing anything, you see all of it in the code i sent

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are using twice `server.quit()` and get the SMTPServerDisconnect on the second call. The reason is the `with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(...) as server`. It disconnects at end of `with` block an implicit `server.quit()`. So when you later use `server.quit()`, `server` is already disconnected, hence the error.

How to fix: just remove the (useless) `server.quit()` and use:

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()

try:
 with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
   server.login(sender_email, password)
   server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message1)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```